# Why can't access struct pointer outside of function

Tags: c, if-statement, pointers, compiler-errors, dereference

Describe Issue:
I'm able to access buffer variable inside of malloc function and can retrieve and set data with no issues

any attempt to access *(buffer+ insert some index here)->data outside of malloc function results in following error

```
mem* demo = malloc(2);
if(*(demo+1)->data == 0x00) {
... do some stuff here 
}
```

following error is produced by gcc cross compiler

```
kernel.c:96:21: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int')
   96 |         if(*(demo+1)->data == 0x00) {
```

Code:

```c
//Licensed under public domain
//also please note there is no standart library this is on a embedded system

typedef struct{
    _Bool allocated;
    unsigned char data;
} mem;
mem memory[1000];

mem* malloc(size_t size){
    mem* buffer[size];
    unsigned int successfulCounts = 0;
    unsigned int bufferCounter = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(memory); i++){
        //Hey that's available memory for us
        if(memory[i].allocated == 0){
            //because buffer is 16 4 items in memory (16*4)-15*4 can be found like this
            if(successfulCounts < sizeof(buffer)-sizeof(buffer-1)){
                *(buffer+successfulCounts) = &memory[i];
                successfulCounts++;
                memory[i].allocated = 1;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return buffer;    
}


//... some more code that implements stuff like free() and calloc()
```

Odd Findings:

when mem * in function changed to unsigned char and returned `*(buffer+1)` i can access the data for some odd reason and i can get the exact same data i have pushed nothing is corrupted as i expect for some odd reason

Comment: Please fix a [mre]

Comment: @klutt example has been fixed now `gcc in.c -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o test.elf` needs a int main() though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This if statement

```
if(*(demo+1)->data == 0x00) {
```

is equivalent to

```
if( *( ( demo + 1 )->data ) == 0x00) {
```

but `data` is not a pointer. It has the type `unsigned char`

```
typedef struct{
    _Bool allocated;
    unsigned char data;
} mem;
```

It seems you mean

```
if( (demo+1)->data == 0x00) {
```

Pay attention to that the function in any case is invalid

```
mem* malloc(size_t size){
    mem* buffer[size];
    //...
    return buffer;    
}
```

For starters the return type of the function is `mem *` while the type of the returned expression is `mem **`. And moreover the function returns a pointer to a local object (array). So the returned pointer will not be invalid because the array will not be alive after exiting the function.

Comment: still the same issue kernel.c:96:20: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int')
   96 |         if((demo+1)->data == 0x00) {

Comment: @lplplplp The expression demo + 1 does not have the type int. it is a pointer provided that it is defined like mem* demo = malloc(2);

Comment: No it is not -- `->` is higher precedence than `*`, so it is equivalent to `if (*((demo+1)->data) == 0x00)`

Comment: From the error message provided, `demo` has type `int` (as does `demo + 1`), so the `demo` in the statement with the error is not the `demo` in the earlier declaration.  That's why an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is so important.

Comment: @ChrisDodd You are right. I was not attentive. But now I can not remove the answer because it is marked as the best.:)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are de-referencing the pointer before using the arrow operator (->).

The arrow operator(->) is used when you want to access a member of a struct using a pointer.

```
struct new_t
{
    char *str;
    int num;
};

struct new_t p1 = {"Dog", 5};
struct *ptr = &p;

char *s = ptr->str; //is valid

char *s1 = ptr.str; // is not valid

char *s2 = *(ptr)->str; // is not valid
```

Whereas the dot(.) operator is used to access a member of a struct

```
int n = p1.num; //is valid

n = p1->num; //is not valid
```

To solved your problem used this

```
if(*(demo+1).data == 0x00) {
... do some stuff here 
}
```

or

```
if((demo+1)->data == 0x00) {
... do some stuff here 
}
```